# Spotify Stops when I open my react native app

Tags: react-native, spotify, audio-player, react-native-video

When I first open my app Spotify music stops after that when I go back and turn on the music and come back to the my app, it works fine. I am using react-native video library for Splash screen and video doesn't have audio and also muted by component props.
Is there any way to keep music alive when I open my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently i face this problem,

i think you are using

1. react-native-video
2. react-native-camera

These 2 libraries pause the playback music

so you need to follow these steps to resolve this problem,

**react-native-video**

**ignoreSilentSwitch**
Controls the iOS silent switch behavior

1. **ignoreSilentSwitch:** "obey" - Don't play audio if the silent switch is set
2. **mixWithOthers**: "mix" - Audio from this video mixes with audio from other apps.

code Snippet:

```
 <Video 
   ....
    ignoreSilentSwitch="obey"
    mixWithOthers={'mix'}
   ....
 />
```

**react-native-camera**

```
 <RNCamera
   .....
    captureAudio={false}
   .....

 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your AppDelegate.m

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i have tried to add the AVFoundation package for IOS, but when i compile the React Native App its create some issue AVAudioSession not found.